# Are gradient fonts supported in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, uicolor, uifont

I'm looking to add a gradient to my UIButton title text. Any solution I find seems to involve overriding drawRect with lower level drawing code.

Is there no out-of-the-box support for gradient text in iOS?

Comment: There's no such thing as "gradient text".

Answer (score 1):

FXLabel is the answer. Example of its output [here](http://i1-scripts.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/FXLabel_1.png).
Github project [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel).